# Recursive generics forbidden?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I want to tie 2 classes to each other at compile time:

```
class Test<A extends Test<A, B>, B extends Test<B, A>> {}
class Foo extends Test<Foo, Bar> {}
class Bar extends Test<Bar, Foo> {}
```

However, it compiles with the error

```
type argument B is not within bounds of type-variable A
```

But I don't see any problems in the code.

UPD. Compiled with 7u40 without errors. Errors with 1.7.0_06-ea-b07

Comment: Are the two classes in the same package?

Comment: @chrylis for example, yes

Comment: And *the example* doesn't work? It compiles just fine for me.

Comment: It seems to compile on my machine. Is that the compiler error or runtime error?

Comment: It compiles just fine in my environment.

Comment: @RohitJain I suspect his "example" is a trimmed-down version of a nested class structure, where the name of the inner class isn't visible at the top-level declaration (I've run into this exact issue before), in which case the fix is to place the partially- or fully-qualified class name in the generic argument.

Comment: @chrylis no - the problem was in outdated early-access compiler.

Comment: @leventov So the answer is Don't Do That Then! ;-)